# Using PHP in need two array value in one array

Tags: php, arrays, decode, encode

so the output is already shared formate. the final array should me array one value and array two value without any 0 and 1 index only the second array value need to add the same response

```
**// array one 
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => success
    [status_code] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [email] => naeemmalik036@gmail.com
        )
    [http_response] => 200
)
// array two 
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => success
    [status_code] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [name] => ram
        )
    [http_response] => 200
)
// output  needed like this  //
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => success
    [status_code] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [email] => naeemmalik036@gmail.com
            [name] => ram
        )
    [http_response] => 200
)**
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? If you don't have current code, nor do you know how you'd design this on paper regardless of code implementation, then you need to do some [additional research](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), make an attempt and, if you still have trouble, come back with your code and explain what you have tried.

Comment: these two array value in need in one array // // output needed like this  //

Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [message] => success
    [status_code] => 0
    [data] => Array
        (
            [email] => naeemmalik036@gmail.com
            [name] => ram
        )

    [http_response] => 200
)

Comment: merge the `data` only or everything? you could manually assign value to array or use `array_merge` (e.g. `$first_array['data'] = array_merge($first_array['data'], $second_array['data'])`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Simply Merge The Array And Re-Assign To Any Array

```
$array2['data'] = array_merge($array['data'],$array2['data']);
print_r($array2);
```